# ffmpeg convert yuv400p16le to yuv42016le

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert yuv400p16le file to yuv420p16le file with ffmpeg.

This command is not working with error.
Please help....

```
ffmpeg -i OutVID00_depth_3840x2160_yuv400p16le.yuv -pix_fmt yuv420p16le -c:v rawvideo -an -s 3840x2160 -y output.yuv
```

[IMGUTILS @ 0000009a769ff1c0] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
OutVID00_depth_3840x2160_yuv400p16le.yuv: Invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is 3840x2160, gray16le, input syntax is

```
ffmpeg -video_size 3840x2160 -pixel_format gray16le -i OutVID00_depth_3840x2160_yuv400p16le.yuv ...
```